# How to find non-overlapping duration with pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, overlap

I'm trying to find the total "active" time between a set of timestamps. For example, if I have:

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 12/1/2020 17:13:10 | 12/1/2020 17:54:38 |
| 12/1/2020 17:13:34 | 12/1/2020 17:37:10 |
| 12/1/2020 17:54:19 | 12/1/2020 18:15:23 |
| 12/1/2020 18:03:08 | 12/1/2020 18:04:51 |
| 12/1/2020 18:17:25 | 12/1/2020 18:25:18 |
| 12/1/2020 18:28:43 | 12/1/2020 18:53:06 |

The active time periods are:

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 12/1/2020 17:13:10 | 12/1/2020 18:15:23 |
| 12/1/2020 18:17:25 | 12/1/2020 18:25:18 |
| 12/1/2020 18:28:43 | 12/1/2020 18:53:06 |

From there, I can calculate active duration but I'm having trouble getting from the first table to the second. I've gotten as far as using .shift() to add a third column with the previous row's end timestamp so that I can compare timestamps across rows.

Open to any and all ideas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining rows with overlapping time periods in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804145/combining-rows-with-overlapping-time-periods-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: May you provide us with an expected output