# Determining max concurrency of time blocks within overlapping date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, overlap

I work for a hospital and we're trying to get a handle on operating room usage.  The room situation is getting out of control.  We have providers doing several concurrent procedures and managing several residents at once. I need to figure out how much that is happening. I've read several solutions but they all seem to operate on two values instead of many, or be summing an
existing value.

The first problem to solve was to figure out how many real-world minutes a provider is working.
Overlapping procedures would make it look like one person was in the operating room over 24 hours a day, which obviously isn't possible.

Thanks to [this
awesome solution by Valentino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804145/combining-rows-with-overlapping-time-periods-in-a-pandas-dataframe) I've been able to calculate overlapping times.

Now I need to know what the max number of concurrent procedures is for a provider in one day.
For example, if Dr. Jones starts at 8am and walks into a situation where they have their own procedure, but also two residents need assistance, that's three procedures at the same time.  But maybe late in the day, in a different block of overlapping time, there's a surge. Now Dr. Jones is running between three different operating rooms and still managing two residents, that jumps up to five concurrent procedures.

Valentino's solution sorts the rows in the initial dataframe into groups of overlapping times:

```
null AN_DATE     AN_PROV_ID USER_ID PROV_NAME  AN_BEGIN_LOCAL_DTTM    AN_END_LOCAL_DTTM        MINS  group
2    2019-07-17         700   JB007   J. Bond  2019-07-17 08:00:00  2019-07-17 09:00:00    01:00:00      1
3    2019-07-17         700   JB007   J. Bond  2019-07-17 08:00:00  2019-07-17 09:30:00    01:30:00      1
5    2019-07-17         700   JB007   J. Bond  2019-07-17 09:00:00  2019-07-17 10:15:00    01:15:00      1
6    2019-07-17         700   JB007   J. Bond  2019-07-17 13:00:00  2019-07-17 14:00:00    01:00:00      2
7    2019-07-17         700   JB007   J. Bond  2019-07-17 12:30:00  2019-07-17 13:30:00    01:00:00      2
```

To get the number of concurrent procedures, can I use the same merged dataframe used to calculate groups?  At the point that these calculations are possible, merged dataframe looks like this:

```
                 time  what  running  newwin  group
2 2019-07-17 08:00:00     1        1    True      1
3 2019-07-17 08:00:00     1        2   False      1
5 2019-07-17 09:00:00     1        3   False      1
2 2019-07-17 09:00:00    -1        2   False      1
3 2019-07-17 09:30:00    -1        1   False      1
5 2019-07-17 10:15:00    -1        0   False      1
7 2019-07-17 12:30:00     1        1    True      2
6 2019-07-17 13:00:00     1        2   False      2
7 2019-07-17 13:30:00    -1        1   False      2
6 2019-07-17 14:00:00    -1        0   False      2
```

I thought at first that I could simply count the number of ones (1) on each group.  But that is not actually concurrency.  In the example below, the block of time is correctly merged into a start time of 8am and end time of 10:15am because of overlapping procedures, but the max number of concurrent procedures for that block is 2:

```
       8am    9am    10am
proc1  ########
proc2  ############
proc3           ###########
```

For the block below the max concurrency would be 3:

```
       8am    9am    10am
proc1  ########
proc2  ############
proc3        ######
proc4           ###########
proc5                 ##
```

It seems like I should be able to use pandas.Interval.overlaps, but that operates on
two intervals.  I'll have 1 to x intervals. So that led
me to consider [pandas.Series.cummax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html#pandas.Series.cummax). But I don't actually have a value to be comparing. In fact every solution I've found either operates on two values or the summation of an already present value. So would I somehow getting the cummax of Interval.overlaps?  That seems way too abstract. I'm too new to this and I don't  understand how these pieces fit together so I appreciate any insights.

Comment: if start times and end times coincide - say in the first case, proc1 ended at 9 and proc2 started at 9, would that count as 2 for concurrency or 1

Comment: The times are rounded down to the minute.  In other words, 8:59:59 seconds would count as 8:59 and 9:00:01 would count as 9:00AM.  So yes, my understanding is that a procedure that ends at 9:00AM and one that begins at 9:00AM would be concurrent.  Thanks.

Comment: in that case - you can get the max concurrency by just looking at the `max` of the `running` column that you show - a cummax seems unnecessary

Comment: Thank you Asish, I will give that a try!

Comment: That did work!  I appreciate the tip.  I can't accept this because it isn't an answer.

Comment: feel free to post what worked and accept it :) feeling lazy right now