# Joining two datasets based on overlapping time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I am trying to "merge" two Dataframe based on overlapping intervals as below:

Dataset 1

| start_date | end_date | field1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-06-30 | A |
| 2020-07-01 | 2020-12-31 | B |

Dataset 2

| start_date | end_date | field2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-04-30 | D |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020-08-31 | E |
| 2020-09-01 | 2020-12-31 | F |

Combined Dataset

| start_date | end_date | field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-04-30 | A | D |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020-06-30 | A | E |
| 2020-07-01 | 2020-08-31 | B | E |
| 2020-09-01 | 2020-12-31 | B | F |

The code is python for the example would be the following

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01','2020-06-30','A'],
                    ['2020-07-01','2020-12-31','B']], 
                     columns = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'field1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01','2020-04-30','D'],
                    ['2020-05-01','2020-08-31','E'],
                    ['2020-09-01','2020-12-31','F']], 
                     columns = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'field2'])


expected_output = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01','2020-04-30','A','D'],
                                ['2020-05-01','2020-06-30','A','E'],
                                ['2020-07-01','2020-08-31','B','E'],
                                ['2020-09-01','2020-12-31','B','F']], 
                                columns = ['start_date', 'end_date','field1', 'field2'])
```

I have really tried to think about ways to do it but I must say my page is blank ... Thanks a lot in advance for any recommendation !

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804145/combining-rows-with-overlapping-time-periods-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for sharing, but it is a slightly different problem.

Comment: @Cambyst What you could do is compare each date range (start-end) in df1 to each in df2 and find the intersecting date ranges (remembering the field1 and field2 values).  Each non-null intersection becomes a row in expected_output.  I don't have time to create a real answer for this right now.  But maybe this can point you or someone else in the right direction.

Comment: @jch  My solution has the same idea as yours.  I was doing a final prettifying of the codes at the time you post your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in these steps:

1. For `df1`, define date range for each row by `pd.date_range()` corresponding to the period from  `start_date` to `end_date` for each row
2. Similarly, for `df2` define date range for each row in similar way
3. Explode the list of dates in newly created `date_range` for each of `df1` and `df2` into multiple rows with each date in a row.
4. Perform an inner merge on `df1` and `df2` on the `date_range` columns in each dataframe.  Now, we can already get the intersections of the common dates in each original dataframe for further processing.
5. Group by `field1` and `field2` on the intersection dates, we can get the new `start_date` of the common date range by taking the first entry in the group.
6. Similarly, we can get the new `end_date` of the common date range by taking the last entry in the group.
7. Finally, we aggregate the entries and take only the first row in each group which already has all the required information we want.

---

```
df1a = (df1.assign(date_range=df1.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['start_date'], end=x['end_date']), axis=1))
           .explode('date_range'))
df2a = (df2.assign(date_range=df2.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['start_date'], end=x['end_date']), axis=1))
           .explode('date_range'))
df3 = df1a.merge(df2a, on='date_range')
df3['start_date'] = df3.groupby(['field1', 'field2'])['date_range'].transform('first')
df3['end_date'] = df3.groupby(['field1', 'field2'])['date_range'].transform('last')
df4 = df3.groupby(['field1', 'field2']).agg('first').reset_index()[['start_date', 'end_date', 'field1', 'field2']]



print(df4)

  start_date   end_date field1 field2
0 2020-01-01 2020-04-30      A      D
1 2020-05-01 2020-06-30      A      E
2 2020-07-01 2020-08-31      B      E
3 2020-09-01 2020-12-31      B      F
```